# Certain javascript libs not loading over https

Tags: python, nginx, https, jquery-select2

After setting up https on a site, some the javascript libraries are not loading while others are. In this case, the select2 lib is not loading. Why would this be?

**Head extract**

```
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://d1r6do663ilw4i.cloudfront.net/static/sweetalerts/sweetalert.css">
    <script src="https://d1r6do663ilw4i.cloudfront.net/static/sweetalerts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have something like Firebug in your browser? Does it show a GET request for the select2 lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Make sure the file actually exists at that URL. (Try different browsers, command line tools, ...)

Second: Make sure your ad-blocker/browser-plugins aren't blocking the request.

Comment: Thanks - the first file https://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css is only available over http - this caused the loading of everything else to fail